# How to ensure scheduling errors don't happen in superscalar chips

Tags: assembly, embedded, gcc

I like to wrap my asm in C subroutines. Like this:

```
void foo()
{
     __asm__("op R0, R1");
     ...
     __asm__("op R1, R4"); /* last instruction */
}
```

When I do this I sometimes get scheduling errors and my code crashes. When writing the subroutines in pure ABI compliant ASM it sometimes causes other parts of my C code to not run correctly but, doesn't crash.

Is there anything I can do to help/make GCC prevent scheduling errors.

Comment: When you say "scheduling error", what exactly do you mean? Do you mean gcc is reordering your instructions in a way that doesn't preserve their meaning? Or something else? Can you give a concrete example?

Comment: As a relatively concrete programming problem, this probably belongs on SO - if you can make it a little more specific.

Answer (score 1):

You can not assume the compiler generates code that doesn't use registers; or that the compiler has any idea what your inline assembly does. *Note: For some compilers, the compilers might infer things directly from the assembly, but this is hard to do for compilers that only support a small number of architectures, and almost impossible for something like GCC that supports a massive variety of different architectures.*

In general, GCC uses things like "clobber lists" so that the compiler can know what the assembly has modified, and input/output parameter lists to pass values into/out of each separate piece of inline assembly.

If you don't use the input parameters, output parameters and clobber lists correctly, then it's not GCC's fault if your assembly messes up code generated by the compiler or if the compiler generated code messes up your assembly.

For more information, I'd suggest: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm

Comment: My assembly isn't messing up. When my assembly runs it runs well. Rather I have inconsistent scheduling issues.